# Geometric $k$-blades

Tags: algebraic-geometry, intuition

What are the purposes of $k$-blades? Why is it important to have a oriented area, or an oriented volume? I'm referring to $k$-blades in such a way that $$\hat{v_1} \wedge \cdots \wedge \hat{v_k} $$ produces a $k$ dimension oriented figure.

What purpose do these serve?

[image]

Comment: This question is very broad. I suggest for a start to read some parts of the Wikipedia article. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form

Answer (score 2):

For the same reason that it's important to have vectors, which are "oriented lengths."  They're part of the natural setting for differential geometry.